# Reloading MVC Partial View

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial

Ok so i have a partial view of a visualisation ( d3 partition ).
The data and details are populated into the partial view via a .js file which is updated using a c# backend that pulls the data from a sql database and puts it into the correct format.

My problem is, i would like to repopulate this partition with different results ( by country ) based on a selection a user does in the main page.

I have been playing around with ajax and onchange events to call the backend population code. This works, however i believe my problem is that i am writing to the .js file that populates the partial view. the location i am writing to is the local\source\repos\MVC\scripts.... folder. once the MVC instance is loaded into the website, i believe the only how i could get to change the partial view using this method is by refreshing the entire page.

What i would like to know is if there is a way i could write to the hosted .js file and let the ajax code update the visualisation with the updated information.

Main View

```
<table class="tg">
<tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">@Html.Partial("SPPDVis1")</td>

    <td class="tg-0lax">@Html.Partial("SPPDVis2")</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">@Html.Partial("SPPDVis3")</td>

    <td class="tg-0lax">@Html.Partial("SPPDVis4")</td>


</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="DataPartition" class="tg-0lax">

        @Html.DropDownList("Partitionbox", Model.Countries, "Select Country")

        <button id="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Data</button>



        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Partitionbox").change(function () {
                var id = $(this).find(":selected").text()
                var selectid = { "id": id }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("RefreshView")',
                    data: JSON.stringify(selectid),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Variable data contains the data you get from the action method
                        $('#DPartition').load(data);

                    },


                });
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div id="DPartition">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("DataPartition");}

        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

DataPartition Partial View

```html
    @model sb_admin_2.Web.Models.CWCountriesISOandCoordinates_MemberModel

@{ 
   // sb_admin_2.Web.ContentBuilder.PartitionBuilder.TradeVisual("Export", "Barbados", "X2015");
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="Partition">
    <div id="top">
      

    </div>
    <div id="footer">

        <div class="hint"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var w = 600,
        h = 400,
        x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]);
    var vis = d3.select("#top").append("div")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .style("width", w + "px")
        .style("height", h + "px")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
    var partition = d3.layout.partition()
        .value(function (d) {
            return d.size;
        });

    data = flare;

    createchart(data);

    function refreshview() {
        setInterval(function () { $('#contributors').load('/Home/GetContributor'); }, 10000); // every 3 sec
    };

    function createchart(root) {
        var g = vis.selectAll("g")
            .data(partition.nodes(root))
            .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.y) + "," + y(d.x) + ")"; })
            .on("click", click);
        var kx = w / root.dx,
            ky = h / 1;
        g.append("svg:rect")
            .attr("width", root.dy * kx)
            .attr("height", function (d) { return d.dx * ky; })
            .attr("class", function (d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; });
        g.append("svg:text")
            .attr("transform", transform)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("opacity", function (d) { return d.dx * ky > 12 ? 1 : 0; })
            .text(function (d) { return d.name + ": $" + d.size; })
        d3.select(window)
            .on("click", function () { click(root); })
        function click(d) {
            if (!d.children) return;
            kx = (d.y ? w - 40 : w) / (1 - d.y);
            ky = h / d.dx;
            x.domain([d.y, 1]).range([d.y ? 40 : 0, w]);
            y.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
            var t = g.transition()
                .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.y) + "," + y(d.x) + ")"; });
            t.select("rect")
                .attr("width", d.dy * kx)
                .attr("height", function (d) { return d.dx * ky; });
            t.select("text")
                .attr("transform", transform)
                .style("opacity", function (d) { return d.dx * ky > 12 ? 1 : 0; });
            d3.event.stopPropagation();
        }
        function transform(d) {
            return "translate(8," + d.dx * ky / 2 + ")";
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('footer').append(footer);
    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.classList.add("hint");
    ele.append(hint);
    document.getElementById('footer').appendChild(ele);
</script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RefreshView(string id)
    {
        sb_admin_2.Web.ContentBuilder.PartitionBuilder.TradeVisual("Export", id, "X2015");

        return PartialView("DataPartition");
    }
```

.jS Data file

```js
footer="Grenada Export -X2015 (US$ 000)"; 
hint="click or option-click to descend or ascend"; 
flare={"name": "Grenada", "size":33.198, "children": [ { "name": "Anguilla", "size": 8.225, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 0.028},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.057},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.191},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 7.949}  ]}, { "name": "Argentina", "size": 35.374, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 33.882},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.805},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.214},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 0.106},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.367}  ]}, { "name": "Aruba", "size": 3.146, "children": [  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.005},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.348},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 2.793}  ]}, { "name": "Austria", "size": 212.031, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 211.925},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.017},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.04},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.049}  ]}, { "name": "Belgium", "size": 464.37, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 435.776},  { "name": "    Mineral fuels, lubricants and related materials", "size": 0.049},  { "name": "    Animal and vegetable oils, fats and waxes", "size": 26.749},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 1.796},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.001}  ]}, { "name": "Bermuda", "size": 1.536, "children": [  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.41},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.366},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 0.082},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.678}  ]}, { "name": "British Virgin Islands", "size": 3.11, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 0.92},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.128},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.103},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 1.922},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.037}  ]}, { "name": "Cayman Islands", "size": 1.383, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 0.066},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.004},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.018},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.012},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 1.282}  ]}, { "name": "China", "size": 65.715, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 0.483},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 5.057},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.559},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 8.965},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 17.909},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 32.742}  ]}, { "name": "China, Hong Kong SAR", "size": 1.246, "children": [  ]}, { "name": "China, Taiwan Province of", "size": 200.828, "children": [  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.157},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 63.856},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 62.459},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 1.572},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 72.783}  ]}, { "name": "Colombia", "size": 3.484, "children": [  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.004},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 0.035},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 3.445}  ]}, { "name": "Costa Rica", "size": 6.182, "children": [  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 3.143},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 2.161},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.878}  ]}, { "name": "Croatia", "size": 30.973, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 16.729},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.349},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 13.793},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 0.043},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.059}  ]}, { "name": "Curaçao", "size": 28.35, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 2.972},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.001},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.006},  { "name": "    Mineral fuels, lubricants and related materials", "size": 1.15},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.268},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 1.812},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 19.661},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 2.481}  ]}, { "name": "Denmark", "size": 1.727, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 0.077},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.036},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.047},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 1.568}  ]}, { "name": "Dominican Republic", "size": 279.041, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 44.492},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.809},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.401},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 65.852},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 144.16},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 23.326}  ]}, { "name": "Faeroe Islands", "size": 0.467, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 0.467}  ]}, { "name": "Finland", "size": 39.29, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 11.399},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.485},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 13.334},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 9.751},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 4.321}  ]}, { "name": "France", "size": 1643.027, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 403.933},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.065},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 6.879},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 75.026},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 584.388},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 530.547},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 42.189}  ]}, { "name": "Germany", "size": 765.818, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 570.267},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.122},  { "name": "    Mineral fuels, lubricants and related materials", "size": 0.651},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.796},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 18.166},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 173.28},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 2.537}  ]}, { "name": "Indonesia", "size": 28.348, "children": [  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 1.229},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 10.524},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 15.761},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 0.833}  ]}, { "name": "Ireland", "size": 34.359, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 1.553},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.067},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 7.719},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 10.614},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 6.124},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 8.282}  ]}, { "name": "Italy", "size": 228.44, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 17.395},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.63},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.367},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 210.048}  ]}, { "name": "Japan", "size": 1270.124, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 10.116},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 2.575},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 10.826},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 1.239},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 1196.935},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 48.434}  ]}, { "name": "Kazakhstan", "size": 2.718, "children": [  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 1.951},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.767}  ]}, { "name": "Korea, Republic of", "size": 44.818, "children": [  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 4.255},  { "name": "    Mineral fuels, lubricants and related materials", "size": 0.489},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 2.286},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 5.457},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 31.492},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.839}  ]}, { "name": "Montenegro", "size": 15.437, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 2.021},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.066},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 2.235},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 10.701},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.414}  ]}, { "name": "Montserrat", "size": 82.539, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 80.064},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 1.587},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.887}  ]}, { "name": "Netherlands", "size": 942.759, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 839.112},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 6.453},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 4.143},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 7.799},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 77.175},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 8.076}  ]}, { "name": "Norway", "size": 84.922, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 84.613},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 0.309}  ]}, { "name": "Peru", "size": 0.876, "children": [  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.867},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 0.01}  ]}, { "name": "Suriname", "size": 46.438, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 2.332},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 3.032},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 27.275},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 13.799}  ]}, { "name": "Sweden", "size": 4.298, "children": [  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.336},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 3.896},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.066}  ]}, { "name": "Switzerland", "size": 138.597, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 122.571},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.026},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 1.154},  { "name": "    Animal and vegetable oils, fats and waxes", "size": 1.151},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.883},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 6.648},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 6.164}  ]}, { "name": "Thailand", "size": 191.886, "children": [  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 158.009},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 3.678},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 4.867},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 25.088},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.243}  ]}, { "name": "United States", "size": 4486.04, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 3383.599},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 146.579},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 15.454},  { "name": "    Mineral fuels, lubricants and related materials", "size": 4.045},  { "name": "    Animal and vegetable oils, fats and waxes", "size": 3.535},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 121.356},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 67.12},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 404.04},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 340.311}  ]}, { "name": "Venezuela (Bolivarian Rep. of)", "size": 24.489, "children": [  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.004},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.051},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 20.786},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 3.648}  ]}, { "name": "Antigua and Barbuda", "size": 616.884, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 376.982},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 9.181},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.091},  { "name": "    Mineral fuels, lubricants and related materials", "size": 2.957},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 2.399},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 188.983},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 27.906},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 8.386}  ]}, { "name": "Bahamas", "size": 10.16, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 0.048},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.006},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.178},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 3.496},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 6.432}  ]}, { "name": "Barbados", "size": 1460.971, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 437.987},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 17.731},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 15.347},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 23.578},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 551.659},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 33.519},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 381.151}  ]}, { "name": "Canada", "size": 547.263, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 491.833},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 2.532},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.005},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.286},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 5.096},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 42.056},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 5.454}  ]}, { "name": "Dominica", "size": 2524.541, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 1666.042},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.028},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.329},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 29.094},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 448.682},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 362.23},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 18.135}  ]}, { "name": "Guyana", "size": 367.196, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 6.167},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 24.546},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 9.323},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.909},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 321.509},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 4.321},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.421}  ]}, { "name": "India", "size": 25.976, "children": [  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 5.886},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 3.668},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 1.769},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 1.623},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 8.295},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 4.736}  ]}, { "name": "Jamaica", "size": 403.284, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 162.052},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.004},  { "name": "    Mineral fuels, lubricants and related materials", "size": 1.184},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 1.241},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 228.698},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 5.771},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 4.333}  ]}, { "name": "Malaysia", "size": 105.211, "children": [  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 10.742},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 2.07},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 10.448},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 76.402},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 5.548}  ]}, { "name": "Nigeria", "size": 8477.15, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 627.353},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 399.865},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 2391.931},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 2257.842},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 1314.543},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 1485.615}  ]}, { "name": "Pakistan", "size": 5.264, "children": [  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 0.031},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 0.168},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 0.314},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 4.737},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 0.013}  ]}, { "name": "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "size": 1418.357, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 1145.933},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 2.741},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 34.926},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 15.811},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 196.997},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 9.149},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 12.8}  ]}, { "name": "Saint Lucia", "size": 2051.763, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 1233.615},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 100.57},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.095},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 216.334},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 336.26},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 153.453},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 11.435}  ]}, { "name": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "size": 590.435, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 51.824},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 43.146},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.672},  { "name": "    Mineral fuels, lubricants and related materials", "size": 10.454},  { "name": "    Animal and vegetable oils, fats and waxes", "size": 0.413},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 232.088},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 86.194},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 85.317},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 80.325}  ]}, { "name": "Trinidad and Tobago", "size": 464.045, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 207.03},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 21.538},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 5.583},  { "name": "    Mineral fuels, lubricants and related materials", "size": 3.7},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 39.11},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 20.701},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 152.429},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 13.954}  ]}, { "name": "Uganda", "size": 8.292, "children": [  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 8.272},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 0.02}  ]}, { "name": "United Kingdom", "size": 2009.801, "children": [  { "name": "    Food and live animals", "size": 80.687},  { "name": "    Beverages and tobacco", "size": 32.431},  { "name": "    Crude materials, inedible, except fuels", "size": 0.954},  { "name": "    Chemicals and related products, n.e.s.", "size": 20.647},  { "name": "    Manufactured goods", "size": 13.51},  { "name": "    Machinery and transport equipment", "size": 1832.527},  { "name": "    Miscellaneous manufactured articles", "size": 29.045}  ]}]};
```

the code to populate this .js file i can obtain the string version of it if that helps.

I know this is a bit much, but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT-

```
string  filepath = @"C:\Users\kr.williams\source\repos\MVCBootstrap\sb-admin-2.Web\Scripts\Partition Data.js";

           // File.WriteAllText(filepath, output);

           // filepath = @"C:\Flask\DataPlatform\templates\Partition\partition.html";
            File.WriteAllText(filepath, html);
```

This is where i write to the .js file. I have a strong feeling this is the wrong location to write to for a web instance. It may also be a completely incorrect implementation of what im doing.

If i pass the .js code back to the view as string, is there a way i could treat it as a java script code and pull out the different variables returned? ( i.e footer,hint ,flare ), then reset those variables and reload the view ?

Could someone advice me ?

Comment: Hello. Your partial view doesn't seem to have a Model passed to it? If the call to sb_admin_2 takes in the id parameter, shouldn't this return the new data that the partial view is to display / manipulate?

Comment: So the sb_admin_2 function that the id is passed to only changes actual .js file stored in the solution. ( which i am assuming is my problem ). i need to know the correct way to populate the data variable in my partial view script with the result from the sb_admin function call

Comment: So just so I understand.. the admin function actually returns JavaScript text which has been tailored to the data governed by "id".. and then is manually embed in the partial view?

Comment: yes, the admin function returns a string that is basically in javascript format and writes it to a .js file that is located inside of my solution. the partial view reads from that file to generate the visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of fiddling and breaking and fixing i figured out the solution that worked for me.

As suggested above, i passed my string over from the data population function to the action, then to the view using a model. However it was not that simple. the createchart function expects a json object (took me a while to figure out that was the problem). passing the string as is to a variable in the partial view did a lot of terrible things with double quotations and single quotes that were inside the string. i eventually realised that string needed to be passed as a json to see the quotations properly in the view.

Once that was sorted it was just cleaning up whatever i broke trying to figure out the issue.

Partial View snippet

```
 var string = JSON.parse(@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.flare))));

    //data = flare;

    createchart(string);
```

Controller snippet

```
public ActionResult RefreshView(int id)
    {

        CWDataSetsEntities aCWDatasetEntity = new CWDataSetsEntities();

        int intCountryID = Convert.ToInt32(id);

        CWCountriesISOandCoordinates aCWCountry = new CWCountriesISOandCoordinates();

        aCWCountry = (from x in aCWDatasetEntity.CWCountriesISOandCoordinates where x.index == intCountryID select x).SingleOrDefault();
        string Country = aCWCountry.Country_Name;

        Models.PartitionViewModels Data = sb_admin_2.Web.ContentBuilder.PartitionBuilder.TradeVisual("Export", Country, "X2015");

        //sb_admin_2.Web.Models.PartitionViewModels.Javascript = Data;
        ViewBag.Data = Data;

        return PartialView("DataPartition", Data);
    }
```

Event script

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#Partitionbox").change(function (e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("#DataPart").remove();
        $('#hint').remove();
        $('#footer').remove();
        $("#TestTarget").load("/Home/RefreshView/" + val);
                    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some specific requirement to use the partial view, you can find how to reload in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122268/updating-partial-view-with-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp). Look at the second answer, that one is better.

Now, assuming you only want to repopulate the chart, why not just call the "createchart" function again after your data is changed in the .js file? Then you will not have to use partial view at all.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Partitionbox").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).find(":selected").text()
    var selectid = {
      "id": id
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("RefreshView")',
      data: JSON.stringify(selectid),
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data) {
        // Variable data contains the data you get from the action method
        //$('#DPartition').load(data);

        createchart(data);
      },


    });
  });

  var w = 600,
    h = 400,
    x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]);
  var vis = d3.select("#top").append("div")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .style("width", w + "px")
    .style("height", h + "px")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
  var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.size;
    });

  var data = flare;

  createchart(data);

  function refreshview() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#contributors').load('/Home/GetContributor');
    }, 10000); // every 3 sec
  };

  function createchart(root) {
    var g = vis.selectAll("g")
      .data(partition.nodes(root))
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.y) + "," + y(d.x) + ")";
      })
      .on("click", click);
    var kx = w / root.dx,
      ky = h / 1;
    g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("width", root.dy * kx)
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d.dx * ky;
      })
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return d.children ? "parent" : "child";
      });
    g.append("svg:text")
      .attr("transform", transform)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("opacity", function(d) {
        return d.dx * ky > 12 ? 1 : 0;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name + ": $" + d.size;
      })
    d3.select(window)
      .on("click", function() {
        click(root);
      })

    function click(d) {
      if (!d.children) return;
      kx = (d.y ? w - 40 : w) / (1 - d.y);
      ky = h / d.dx;
      x.domain([d.y, 1]).range([d.y ? 40 : 0, w]);
      y.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
      var t = g.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + x(d.y) + "," + y(d.x) + ")";
        });
      t.select("rect")
        .attr("width", d.dy * kx)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return d.dx * ky;
        });
      t.select("text")
        .attr("transform", transform)
        .style("opacity", function(d) {
          return d.dx * ky > 12 ? 1 : 0;
        });
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }

    function transform(d) {
      return "translate(8," + d.dx * ky / 2 + ")";
    }
  };

  document.getElementById('footer').append(footer);
  var ele = document.createElement("div");
  ele.classList.add("hint");
  ele.append(hint);
  document.getElementById('footer').appendChild(ele);
});
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">@Html.Partial("SPPDVis1")</td>

    <td class="tg-0lax">@Html.Partial("SPPDVis2")</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">@Html.Partial("SPPDVis3")</td>

    <td class="tg-0lax">@Html.Partial("SPPDVis4")</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="DataPartition" class="tg-0lax">

      @Html.DropDownList("Partitionbox", Model.Countries, "Select Country")

      <button id="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Data</button>
      <div id="DPartition">
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope I could help out just a little bit. Happy coding :)

Comment: I think your idea makes sense, however i tried it and its not picking up the change event from the main view. I am assuming thats because there is no #Partitionbox in the partial view. or are you saying i should take the code completely out of the partial view all together ?

Comment: So i got it to recognize the change event.. that was my bad. however it still isnt updating the visual. I am assuming thats because its not getting the updated file from my source after the .js is updated.  Please see edit at the top question for a bit more information

Comment: Would it be possible to just get the data in the function directly and not write it inside the file at all? I think now the problem is you might have written the data in the file, but did not reload the file, thus the changes do not take affect. 

Just load the data with onchange and pass the data to createchart function. If you need to have the full data available to your page, declare a global variable and store it inside.

Comment: Yes, that would be a possible work around. i do not need to have the file there but since i took that code from another project thats how it was done. i can easily edit the .js population code to simply pass the string to a change function, however what i am not sure of is if i could pull out the different variables inside of it like i did  with the .js file. The .js file has 3 variables in it that i populate using the population code. "footer" , "hint" , and "Flare" . i need those three variables separately in different parts of my visualisation script.

Comment: If you put it in file, you have to reload the page to reload the file content. You can just access all the variables like data.footer, data.hint, data.flare from inside the ajax get function. Pass the flare data to createchart, and replace other data targeting id. Don't append though. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks i would try that and get back to you

Comment: So i managed to get the variables passed to the partial view from the action result, however when the action result runs now, the script does not run. if i do a @Model.Data ( thats the name of the model ) inside of the html, the raw data shows there perfectly, however i cant get the script to run to build the visualisation

Comment: Its better to always get the data through a separate action if you are going to change it dynamically. So you don't need to take care of the first time the page loads separately.

If you wish to use the @Model.Data,  an example is here on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361364/accessing-mvcs-model-property-from-javascript

** the global js variable has to be declared inside the html code and outside (document).ready and you have to call createchart from inside the (document).ready