# How to Render PartialView from Json in Mvc 5 with XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, controller, xmlhttprequest, partial-views

**in Html**

```
@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#bSubmit').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('@Html.Get__RequestVerificationTokenString()', '@Html.GetAntiForgeryToken()');
            formData.append('request.MessageId', @Model.MessageId);
            formData.append('request.Message', $('#Message').val());

            var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlHttpRequest.open("POST",
                '@Url.Action("Send", "Page", new {area = "Question"})',
                true);

            xmlHttpRequest.onloadend = function() {
                var response = JSON.parse(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);

                $('#prButton').removeClass("visible");
                $('#prButton').addClass("invisible");

                switch (response.Type) {
                case 10:
                    LOG(response.PartialView);

                    $('#layoutSingleMessageItems .card-box').replaceWith(response.PartialView);
                    break;
                case -13:
                    @Html.ShowAlert("خطا در ارسال اطلاعات!");
                    break;
                }
            };

            xmlHttpRequest.send(formData);

        });

    });

</script>
}
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-7">
        @Html.Partial("Par_SingleMessageItem", Model.SingleMessageItems)
    </div>

<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="card-box">
        <form>
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-form-label">پاسخ</label>
                <textarea rows="8" id="Message" placeholder="لطفا پاسخ خود را وارد کنید ..."></textarea>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-12 m-t-10">

                <button id="bSubmit" type="submit">
                    ارسال پاسخ

                </button>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

**in PartialView (Par_SingleMessageItem)**

```
@model List<_4Wheels.Areas.Question.Models.SingleMessage.SingleMessageItem>

<div id="layoutSingleMessageItems" class="card-box">
    <div class="card-box">
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model)
            { 
                //code
            }
         }
   </div>
</div>
```

**in Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Send() {
   /*
      items = list object
   */

   return Json(new SendAnswerResponse {
       Type = 10,
       SingleMessageItems = PartialView("Par_SingleMessageItem" , items)
   });
}
```

**in SendAnswerResponse**

```
public class SendAnswerResponse : MvcResponse
{
    public PartialViewResult SingleMessageItems { get; set; }
}
```

All this code works fine but `$('#layoutSingleMessageItems .card-box'). replaceWith(response.PartialView);` It doesn't work, it doesn't make any errors Returns the desired **PartialView** just the **tag** is not updated.

**I even put it in Console.log (response.PartialView) to display this message**

> Model: (5) […]
>   ​​
>   0: Object { Message: "fdgdfgdfg", Username: "", MessageDate: "1398-08-06 23:01:11", … }
>   ​​
>   1: Object { Message: "dsafd", Username: "", MessageDate: "1398-08-07 08:34:19", … }
>   ​​
>   2: Object { Message: "vcgdsafd", Username: "", MessageDate: "1398-08-07 08:34:58", … }
>   ​​
>   3: Object { Message: "fdgfdg", Username: "", MessageDate: "1398-08-07 08:42:43", … }
>   ​​
>   4: Object { Message: "fdgfdg", Username: "", MessageDate: "1398-08-07 08:42:54", … }
>   ​​
>   length: 5
>   ​​
>   : Array []
>   ​
>   TempData: Array []
>   ​
>   View: null
>   ​
>   ViewBag: Object {  }
>   ​
>   ViewData: []
>   ​​
>   length: 0
>   ​​
>   : Array []
>   ​
>   ViewEngineCollection: Array [ {…} ]
>   ​
>   ViewName: "Par_SingleMessageItem"
>   ​
>   : {…}
>   ​​
>   **defineGetter**: function **defineGetter**()
>   ​​
>   **defineSetter**: function **defineSetter**()
>   ​​
>   **lookupGetter**: function **lookupGetter**()
>   ​​
>   **lookupSetter**: function **lookupSetter**()
>   ​​
>   **proto**: 
>   ​​
>   constructor: function Object()
>   ​​
>   hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
>   ​​
>   isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
>   ​​
>   propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
>   ​​
>   toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
>   ​​
>   toSource: function toSource()
>   ​​
>   toString: function toString()
>   ​​
>   valueOf: function valueOf()
>   ​​
>   : function **proto**()
>   ​​
>   : function **proto**()
>   Utility.js:13:13

Comment: What is the exception? So can you share view cshtml?

Comment: It doesn't make any mistakes, it just replaces PartialView and it doesn't display anything. @codelover

Comment: I edited my post to see it again. I shared view cshtml. @codelover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated with the following PartialView code**

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewPath, object model = null, bool partial = false)
        {
            // first find the ViewEngine for this view
            ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = null;
            if (partial)
                viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewPath);
        else
            viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, viewPath, null);

        if (viewEngineResult == null)
            throw new FileNotFoundException("View cannot be found.");

        // get the view and attach the model to view data
        var view = viewEngineResult.View;
        context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        string result = null;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var ctx = new ViewContext(context, view, context.Controller.ViewData, context.Controller.TempData, sw);
            view.Render(ctx, sw);
            result = sw.ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static T CreateController<T>(RouteData routeData = null) where T : Controller, new()
    {
        // create a disconnected controller instance
        T controller = new T();

        // get context wrapper from HttpContext if available
        HttpContextBase wrapper;
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
            wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot create Controller Context if no active HttpContext instance is available.");

        if (routeData == null)
            routeData = new RouteData();

        // add the controller routing if not existing
        if (!routeData.Values.ContainsKey("controller") &&
            !routeData.Values.ContainsKey("Controller"))
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", controller.GetType().Name.ToLower().Replace("controller", ""));

        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(wrapper, routeData, controller);
        return controller;
    }
```

**And to Used**

```
return Json(new SendAnswerResponse {
   Type = 10,
   SingleMessageItems = MvcHelper.RenderPartialViewToString(
                    MvcHelper.CreateController<Controller Name>().ControllerContext ,
                    "view Path", items , true)
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42559538/11657764

Answer (score 0):

What does the response.SingleMessageItems return ?
It returns html ? or a data structure?
I think you try something like this

```
for(var i =0; i< response.SingleMessageItems.length; i++)
{
  $('#layoutSingleMessageItems .card-box').append(response.SingleMessageItems[i]);
}
```

Comment: This code didn't work either. I edited my post to see it again.

Comment: I'm sending a PartialView but it doesn't replace it in the tag.

Comment: I think you should replace the content of the partial view, not trying to replace  in $('#layoutSingleMessageItems .card-box') a whole partial view, in the code above you replace the content, using append, html, or load.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122268/updating-partial-view-with-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp